# Passing array of arbitrary length to php through java and handling it within php

Tags: javascript, php, android, arrays, hashmap

I have a HashMap of event-outcome pairs stored as two strings, where the first string can be any positive integer, this represents the id, and the second string is the possible outcome. This can be '1' 'X' or '2'. So for example this would be a valid HashMap:

```
32
9X
81
12X
```

I'm trying to check every one of these Id's with my database using php to check if the outcome in the hashmap is the same as the outcome in the database for that event. The outcomes in the database stored as 'Result' can be either '1' 'X' or '2' or 'null' if the event didn't occur yet. At the moment I'm using a for loop as shown below and creating a new Httpconnection for every ID. This works, however it is incredibly inefficient and I receive "connection refused, TIMEOUT" errors if I try to check a lot of data. I'm sure this can be done by passing an array of ID strings to the php and checking each ID within the php and returning an array of event-outcome pairs back to the android app. However, although I found ways on how to fo pass arrays to php, I have no idea how to incorporate the varying length of the array as in each case the HashMap may be of different length, and I don't know how to work through the array of arbitrary length in php itself. Below is my java class and two php files. Thanks for the help in advance. :)

CheckBet.java

```html
 public String checkbetoutcome() {
        for (String x : bet.keySet()) {
            Log.d("X", x);
            currentitem = x;
            new LoadAllGamet().execute();
        }
        for (String x : statuses) {
            Log.d("testaaaaa",x);
            if (x.equals("open")) {
                finalstatus = "open";
        }
            if (x.equals("lost")) {
                finalstatus = "lost";
                break;
            }
    }
        return finalstatus;
    }
            class LoadAllGamet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
            }
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_check_bet);
                    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 2000000);

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", currentitem));
                    Log.d("CURRENTITEM",currentitem);
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                Log.d("Http Post Responsecxxx:", response.toString());
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
                JSONObject jObj = null;
                String json = "";
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (!line.startsWith("<", 0)) {
                            if (!line.startsWith("(", 0)) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                    json = json.substring(json.indexOf('{'));
                    Log.d("sbsssssssssss", json);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                // return JSON String
                game = jObj.toString().substring((jObj.toString().indexOf(':')+1),(jObj.toString().length()-1));
                Log.d("GAME",game);
                Log.d("jsonsssssssssss", jObj.toString());
                if (game.contains("null")) {
                    String asa = game.substring(game.indexOf("\"") + 1, game.length());
                    game = asa;
                }
                else {
                    String asa = game.substring(game.indexOf("\"")+1,game.length()-1);
                    game = asa;
                }
                Log.d("CURRENTITEMSTATUS",game);
                Log.d("CURRENTITEAMREAL", bet.get(currentitem));
                if (game.equals("null")) {
                    status = "open";
                }
                else if (game.equals(bet.get(currentitem))) {
                    status = "won";
                }
                else  {
                    status = "lost";
                }

                Log.d("Status", status);
                statuses.add(status);
                status = "open";

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
                    return "";

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String param) {

                }
        // CHANGE THIS AT THE END
    }
    }
```

Check_Bets_Handler.php

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['param'])) {
    // get tag
    $array = array();
    $array= $_POST['param'];
 
    // include db handler
     require_once 'include/Check_Bets.php';


    $db = new Check_Bets();
     foreach($array as $id) {

    // response Array
    $result = $db->checkuserbets($id);
    $response["bet"] = array();
    array_push($response["bet"], $result);

           }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "the response is null!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Check_Bets.php

```html
<?php

class Check_Bets {
  
 

   function __construct() {

 require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
 $this->db = new DB_Connect();

 $this->db->connect();


}



function __destruct() {
   
  }

  public function checkuserbets($id) {

   $conn=mysqli_connect("****", "****", "**","******");

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Result FROM gamelist WHERE gid = '$id'");
 $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {

 return mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this solves your purpose, but I have passed an array of uncertain length, and also associative arrays to php using a simple technique.

Assume `param` to be the key to be the hashmap. You can access it in the PHP code as `param [ index ]` to obtain `value`.

Here's a snippet for you:

```
//Assuming you've created a HashMap mHashMap
for (String id : mHashMap.keySet()) {
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param" + "[" + id + "]" , mHashMap.get(id)));
```

You can retrieve this associative array in your PHP script as `$_POST["param"]`. Store this in a variable `array` and access using `array["id"]`.

Hope it helps. Please let me know if you face any trouble with this..

Comment: One question, how do I loop through the array in php itself, since the Id's aren't ordered in any way and can be any number, smaller or greater than the ID before it

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not good with PHP. There must be a way similar to 'ketSet()' as in Java's HashMap. You may spend some time with Google for it.